# HTML AJAX not executing PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I am really new to AJAX/jQuery and PHP, and im trying to work on a little project that writes your daily weight to a Db which then is displayed later on with graphs etc.

I would like when the user submits the form for his or her weight that it displays a pop up message but for whatever reason, the AJAX/Jquery script doesn't seem to be doing anything with the php file therefore no info gets added into the database.

Here is the HTML Form: (index.html)

```
      <form id="ajax-form" method="post" action="connection.php">
        <div class="columns field">
          <div class="column control is-half is-offset-one-quarter">
            <input
              class="input"
              id="weight"
              name="weight"
              type="text"
              placeholder="Enter your weight for the day"
            />
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="center-test">
          <div class="field">
            <div class="control">
              <span class="select">
                <select name="person">
                  <option value="Ayush">Ayush</option>
                  <option value="Sheri">Sheri</option>
                </select>
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <input type="date" name="weightdate" id="weightdate" />
        <div class="field column is-half is-offset-one-quarter">
          <button
            type="submit"
            id="submit"
            name="submit"
            class="button is-primary"
          >
            Submit
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>

      <div id="error_message" class="text-danger"></div>
      <div id="success_message" class="text-success"></div>
```

AJAX/jQuery: (inside index.html )

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
          $("#submit").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var weight = $("#weight").val();
            var person = $("#person").val(); // You miss this
            var weightdate = $("#weightdate").val(); // You miss this
            if (weight == "" || person == "" || weightdate == "") {
              $("#error_message").html("All Fields are required");
            } else {
              $("#error_message").html("");
              $.ajax({
                url: "connection.php",
                method: "POST",
                data: {
                  weight: weight,
                  person: person, // Add this
                  weightdate: weightdate, // Add this
                },
                success: function (data) {
                  $("form").trigger("reset");
                  $("#success_message").fadeIn().html("data");
                  setTimeout(function () {
                    $("#success_message").fadeOut("Slow");
                  }, 2000);
                },
              });
            }
          });
        });
```

PHP: (connection.php)

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
include_once 'dbconnect/db_info.php';


$weight = $_POST['weight'];
$person = $_POST['person'];
$date = $_POST['weightdate'];
$formatDate = date("d/m/y", strtotime($date));
//echo $formatDate;

if(date("m", strtotime($date)) == date("01")) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO WeightTracker (person, kg, weight_date, date_month) VALUES ('$person', '$weight', '$formatDate', 'January');";
    #$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
}
elseif(date("m", strtotime($date)) == date("04")) {
    //echo working;
    $sql = "INSERT INTO WeightTracker (person, kg, weight_date, date_month) VALUES ('$person', '$weight', '$formatDate', 'April');";
    #$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
}
else {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO WeightTracker (person, kg, weight_date) VALUES ('$person', '$weight', '$date');";
    #$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas? When I remove the AJAX/jQuery code, the form successfully submits and the connection.php writes to the database with no issues.

Comment: `the AJAX/Jquery script doesn't seem to be doing anything with the php` - what does this mean?  Be specific. What about some basic debugging, what does your browser devtools show?  Any errors on the console?  Check the network tab, is the AJAX request actually happening?  How does the server respond? Any errors in your web server or php logs?

Comment: Your `person` input is missing the expected `person` ID, but otherwise your code runs fine.  [Here's a working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dont_panic/povt1m7j/) (`/echo/json/` is just how JSFiddle simulates AJAX requests, eg the request to your `connection.php` which doesn't exist there).

Comment: So based on the Devtools, it seems that when I hit the submit button, I can see that connection.php has a green bar that's just hanging like that (seems like its not being processed). Im new to this stuff so I don't really know how to troubleshoot that but when I press the submit button without any jQuery, everything runs perfectly fine. It seems like there's something wrong with my php file but I don't know what's going on...

Comment: On the network tab, click the `connection.php` request to see more info about it.  The *Request* section will show you whatever data was sent with the request, you should see your `weight`, `person` etc data.  The *Response* will show you how the server responded. 200 means all OK, you should also be able to see any data your PHP code sent back (it doesn't look like your PHP code does this, but you probably should, so you know if the PHP worked as expected, or if it failed, why). If you're not seeing a 200/OK response, something went wrong while processing the PHP - check your server logs.

Comment: I updated the JSFiddle to include your success callback. It all works, however you are displaying the text `data` in your `success_message`, not the `data` variable you get back as a response from the AJAX.  Remove the quotes to display the actual response.  However as I wrote above, your PHP does not echo or return anything, so the `data` variable will be blank.

Comment: Thank you for that. Upon further investigations, it seems that there is an undefined index in the connection.php on line 7 that is preventing the request. Line 7 on that file is $person = $_POST['person'];

I don't know where im still going wrong with this though...

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help! its now writing to the database however its not recording the "person". It does when I don't include jQuery. Any ideas?

Comment: Glad to help. I posted an answer with the last piece, pls have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the problem was resolved in comments.  The problem (as described in the comments) was a PHP error `Undefined index` on this line:

```
$person = $_POST['person'];
```

As I mentioned in an earlier comment: your person input is missing the expected person ID.  That means this Javascript:

```
var person = $("#person").val();
```

Is actually undefined, so there is no `person` field POSTed to your PHP, so when you try to use it as `$_POST['person']`, you'll get an error.

To fix that, just add the id your Javascript is using to find the person:

```
<select name="person" id="person">
```

Answer (score 0):

The data you give for the POST request is just `weight`, there is no `person` and `weightdate` data.

```js
var weight = $("#weight").val();
var person = $("#person").val(); // You miss this
var weightdate = $("#weightdate").val(); // You miss this

if (weight == "" || person == "" || weightdate == "") {
    $("#error_message").html("All Fields are required");
} else {
    // Your code :)
}
```

And the `data`,

```js
              $.ajax({
                url: "connection.php",
                method: "POST",
                data: {
                    weight: weight,
                    person: person, // Add this
                    weightdate: weightdate // Add this
                },
                success: function(data) {
                  $("form").trigger("reset");
                  $("#success_message")
                    .fadeIn()
                    .html("data");
                  setTimeout(function() {
                    $("#success_message").fadeOut("Slow");
                  }, 2000);
                }
              });
```

Comment: I have made those changes and it still doesn't work :(

Answer (score -1):

Your Problem lies here.

```
include_once 'dbconnect/db_info.php';
```

Change it to something like

```
realpath('__DIR__'.'/dbconnect/db_info.php');
```

Hopefully it will solve your problem.

Comment: [From the docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php): *include will finally check in the calling script's own directory and the current working directory*